# How to check if a parameter of the current method has an annotation and retrieve that parameter value in Java?

Tags: java, class, reflection, methods, annotations

Consider this code:

```
public example(String s, int i, @Foo Bar bar) {
  /* ... */
}
```

I want to check if the method has an annotation `@Foo` and get the argument or throw an exception if no `@Foo` annotation is found.

My current approach is to first get the current method and then iterate through the parameter annotations:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Util {

    private Method getCurrentMethod() {
        try {
            final StackTraceElement[] stes = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
            final StackTraceElement ste = stes[stes.length - 1];
            final String methodName = ste.getMethodName();
            final String className = ste.getClassName();   
            final Class<?> currentClass = Class.forName(className);
            return currentClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(cause);
        }  
    }

    private Object getArgumentFromMethodWithAnnotation(Method method, Class<?> annotation) {
        final Annotation[][] paramAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();    
            for (Annotation[] annotations : paramAnnotations) {
                for (Annotation an : annotations) {
                    /* ... */
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Is this the right approach or is there a better one?
How would the code inside the forach loop look like? I'm not sure if I have understood the what `getParameterAnnotations` actually returns...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with you have already

Comment: +1 for not doing `new Exception().getStackTrace()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The outer for loop

```
for (Annotation[] annotations : paramAnnotations) {
   ...
}
```

should use an explicit counter, otherwise you don't know what parameter you are processing right now

```
final Annotation[][] paramAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
final Class[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
for (int i = 0; i < paramAnnotations.length; i++) {
    for (Annotation a: paramAnnotations[i]) {
        if (a instanceof Foo) {
            System.out.println(String.format("parameter %d with type %s is annotated with @Foo", i, paramTypes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure your annotation type is annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

From your question it is not entirely clear what you are trying to do. We agree on the difference of formal parameters vs. actual arguments:

```
void foo(int x) { }

{ foo(3); }
```

where `x` is a parameter and `3` is an argument?

It is not possible to get the arguments of methods via reflection. If it is possible at all, you would have to use the `sun.unsafe` package. I can't tell you much about that though.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the actual argument which is annotated with `@Foo`.

Comment: You should create an explicit question for that, as it gets lost between the (unrelated) annotation stuff.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for annotations on the method, you probably want `method.getAnnotations()` or `method.getDeclaredAnnotations()`.

The `method.getParameterAnnotations()` call gives you annotations on the method's formal parameters, not on the method itself.

Looking back at the question title, I suspect you *are* looking for annotations on the parameters, which I didn't read in the content of the question.  If that's the case, your code looks fine.

See [Method Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and [AnnotatedElement Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html).

Answer (score 4):

`getParameterAnnotations` returns an array with the length equals to the amount of method parameters. Each element in that array contains an array of [annotations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) on that parameter.
So `getParameterAnnotations()[2][0]` contains the first (`[0]`) annotation of the third (`[2]`) parameter.

If you only need to check if at least one parameter contains an annotation of a specific type, the method could look like this:

```
private boolean isAnyParameterAnnotated(Method method, Class<?> annotationType) {
    final Annotation[][] paramAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();    
    for (Annotation[] annotations : paramAnnotations) {
        for (Annotation an : annotations) {
            if(an.annotationType().equals(annotationType)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```