# How to get the value of a method argument via reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, annotations, arguments

Consider this code:

```
public void example(String s, int i, @Foo Bar bar) {
    /* ... */
}
```

I'm interested in the value of the argument annotated with `@Foo`. Assume that I have already figured out via reflection (with `Method#getParameterAnnotations()`) which method parameter has the `@Foo` annotation. (I know it is the third parameter of the parameter list.)

How can I now retrieve the value of `bar` for further usage?

Comment: I don't get the question. The value of `bar` will only be available during runtime. Do you want to intercept calls to `example`? Or do you mean the datatype `Bar`?

Comment: look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263342/5050750

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't. Reflection does not have access to local variables, including method parameters.

If you want that functionality, you need to intercept the method call, which you can do in one of several ways:

- AOP (AspectJ / Spring AOP etc.)
- Proxies (JDK, CGLib etc)

In all of these, you would gather the parameters from the method call and then tell the method call to execute. But there's no way to get at the method parameters through reflection.

Update: here's a sample aspect to get you started using annotation-based validation with AspectJ

```
public aspect ValidationAspect {

    pointcut serviceMethodCall() : execution(public * com.yourcompany.**.*(..));

    Object around(final Object[] args) : serviceMethodCall() && args(args){
        Signature signature = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
        if(signature instanceof MethodSignature){
            MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) signature;
            Method method = ms.getMethod();
            Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = 
                method.getParameterAnnotations();
            String[] parameterNames = ms.getParameterNames();
            for(int i = 0; i < parameterAnnotations.length; i++){
                Annotation[] annotations = parameterAnnotations[i];
                validateParameter(parameterNames[i], args[i],annotations);
            }
        }
        return proceed(args);
    }

    private void validateParameter(String paramName, Object object,
        Annotation[] annotations){

        // validate object against the annotations
        // throw a RuntimeException if validation fails
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm already using AspectJ, but I haven't found a way to do it. This was the earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228590/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-of-the-current-method-has-an-annotation-and-retrieve

Comment: @soc OK, see my update for starters, buy [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/) to really learn how to do it (or ask questions on the [AspectJ users list](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/userlists.php)

Comment: Hey thanks! :-) I already bought the book, but I tried to put everything into the match signatures, which didn't work...

Comment: @soc I know. Matching annotations on a variable number of annotations on method parameters just won't work.

Comment: Edit: Mhhh, does this example also work with the annotation syntax? I can't find an approrpiate import for `thisJoinPointStaticPart`.

Comment: @soc with `@AspectJ` syntax, your aspect needs a parameter of type `ProceedingJoinPoint`.