# Map of method arguments in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way by which we can retrieve all the arguments/parameters of a method inside that method in a `Map` with key as parameter name and value as parameter value?

Say, I have a method with below signature:

```
public void do(String arg1, int arg2, String arg3, Double arg4, MyCustomObj arg5)
```

I want to achieve something like this:

`public void do(String arg1, int arg2, String arg3, Double arg4, MyCustomObj arg5) {

    Map<String, Object> argsMap = <what-goes-here>;
    logger.info("do ENTRY: "+argsMap);
}`

PS: I am not looking for a solution based on AOP. I want something that can be used within the method itself.

Update: This question is not about how to get values via Reflection. Please re-read before marking it as duplicate.

Comment: You mean, the parameters to the _current_ method, from _inside_ that method?

Comment: Yes!! Somehow couldn't update the question.

Comment: Take a look at: [How to get the value of a method argument via reflection in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230326/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-method-argument-via-reflection-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a candidate of [AOP](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/simple-introduction-to-aop.html) and [with spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) where you could apply before advice, create your own map and print it.

Comment: You'd still have to create the map manually.

Comment: Yes but it would be within advice and you just need to define it once like: `@Before(..) ..mymethod(..) { create map of args and send it to console and then proceed with normal routine`?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think the question is about how to "magically" obtain the parameters of a method in map form.

Comment: Then that's worse! thanks @biziclop

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
public void function(String... parameters) {
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i += 2) {
        System.out.println(parameters[i] + " " + parameters[i + 1]);
    }
}
```