# is it possible to get annotated method parameter?

Tags: java

currently i am working on custom annotation and i am trying to catch declared annotated method parameter value here is example:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

}

public class CustomAnnotationTest {

  @CustomAnnotation
  public void annotationTest(String address){
    System.out.println("address :" + address);
  }
}
```

here how can i read this annotationTest method parametr value "address" using

@customAnnotation.

thanks.

Comment: `ElementType.PARAMETER`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593597/java-seek-a-method-with-specific-annotation-and-its-annotation-element & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230326/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-method-argument-via-reflection-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can get the annotation from the [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class))

```
 CustomAnnotation customAnnotation = CustomAnnotationTest.class
         .getDeclaredMethod("annotationTest", String.class)
         .getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
```