# How throw exception with annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a class as follow:

```
public class MyClass {
   private String key;

   // Getter And Setter
}
```

I want to limit `key` value(for example it can't have space char), for this I have to define as setter as follow:

```
public void setKey(String key)
{
    if(key.indexOf(" ") != -1)
      throw new RuntimeException("");

    this.key = key;

}
```

I used this setter in another class too, Is it possible to define an annotation that when setter method callded, it checked this?

If yes, How?

Comment: Maybe use bean validation or AOP?

Comment: None of them it is only simple class

Comment: That was more a list of options you could consider than a question about what you're currently using...

Comment: For example what?

Comment: this thread having similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230326/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-method-argument-via-reflection-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using annotations for exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389808/using-annotations-for-exception-handling)

Comment: Adding a one line method call to do the same thing us simpler and faster. Also consider how easy it would be to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.
You would have to write your own Annotation with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` and write some kind of tool which would constantly check the parameter via Reflection.
That's not possible for parameters and neither is it desirable to constantly check every call of that method in every instance of your class.

Instead of trying to solve this with an annotation you could implement some kind of utility class similar to `Objects`:

```
public final class Strings {

    /**
     * Utility classes should not be instantiated.
     */
    private Strings() {}

    public static void requireWhiteSpace(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value should contain a white space character!")
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
public void setKey(String key) {
    Strings.requireWhiteSpace(key);
    this.key = key;
}
```